# update custom layout does not show custom style

Tags: layout, blocks, layout-update, update-handle

I have an extra link for a custom style which is a logo that I should show only in one specific category, category id is 1262 so I did this:

```
<CATEGORY_1262>
    <reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="mybuyscsscode">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link href="https://customlink.com/BreastCancer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="stylecustom">]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</CATEGORY_1262>
```

when I go to the page source I don't see the css in the page. also I did this:

```
<CATEGORY_1262>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link href="https://customlink.com/BreastCancer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="mybuysstyles">]]></text></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_1262>
```

none of them work, I do not have access to the code today so I have to do it by xml update, do I have any options to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to just add below code in custom layout update for that category. It will only add it for that category. So remove `<CATEGORY_1262>` from your layout.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="mybuyscsscode">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link href="https://28166fc2113f28b37ea14b5f7cfe49f060ffe20f.googledrive.com/host/0B4y9LnI3CsdpfjlhYkJnV2ZIRlZHWFZXTmR5SnR6VWVHWXRrOHZnZGVZMmgxcnYxSEhJaGs/BreastCancer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="stylecustom">]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: hey thanks man! :) I will accept when in 7 minuets! I'm curious why then we needed to do catedory_1262